# ffmpeg "Header Missing" error recoding mp3 files

Tags: audio, ubuntu, encoding, ffmpeg, mp3

I have an mp3 encoding server running on Ubuntu (natty). This has been working perfectly up until maybe a week or two ago. I believe I ran an update, which seemed to break the encoder for me - every time I try to run the encode script, it fails out with the error "Header Missing". Files that encoded previously without any issues no longer encode.

I am getting the following output when I run a basic ffmpeg script (that worked fine previously). Any ideas what is going on?

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.6-4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:28:21 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil   configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavcodec  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavformat configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavdevice configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavfilter configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libswscale  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libpostproc configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[mp3 @ 0x8aafbc0]max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mp3, from '1340299085b3da8484f1b089d28460930d1467a749.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TLAN            : eng
    TRCK            : 8/11
    TPE1            : Big Wreck
    TALB            : Albatross
    TYER            : 2012
    TIT2            : Rest Of The World
    Rip date        : 2012-03-07
    TDAT            : 0603
    Source          : CD
    Release type    : Normal release
    TCON            : Rock
    TPUB            : Anthem Entertainment Group
  Duration: 00:02:51.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 320 kb/s
File 'test.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp3, to 'test.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mp3 @ 0x8ab0db0]Header missingrate=  64.0kbits/s    
Error while decoding stream #0.0
size=    1339kB time=171.42 bitrate=  64.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:1339kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.002406%
```

Comment: Please also show your actual ffmpeg command.

Comment: I see `WARNING: library configuration mismatch` as well as a lot of **`--disable-ffmpeg`** in your configuration, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, no fix other than to simply download the newest version of FFMPEG and re-installing from scratch. Not sure what happened with the latest update via apt-get, but it certainly broke something.